# when to use THE in this context?

Tags: articles

Item name: Cold Brew Milk

Cold Brew Milk is filled with chocolate and coffee.

or

The Cold Brew Milk is filled with chocolate and cofee.

Is the article optional in this context?

Comment: Since Cold Brew Milk is a proper name, you would not use *the* in this example.

Comment: Could you provide some additional context? Is this some type of _specific_ menu item being described? If so, I would use "the"; e.g. "The house-made dressing is made of oil and vinegar. Alternatively, if you are describing it as a _general_ food category, I would omit "the"; e.g. "Yogurt is a healthy breakfast."

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on context. If you're referring to the product in general, then it seems reasonable to disclude the article in that case. However, if, for example, you are referring to a single bottle/carton of this product, then the article would be necessary. I don't think the fact that **Cold Brew Milk** is a proper noun determines whether or not an article is necessary, although I can't justify this.